# PHP как рандомно отсортировать в зависимости от параметра?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив и есть запросы с разных сайтов к нему, ну что бы в зависимости от домена, он сортировался рандомно по разному, но в то же время при повторном обращении с одного домена сортировка была бы той же самой...

Как такое реализовать?

В идеале какую нибудь функцию, где на входе массив и параметр (сторока любая), а на выходе в зависимости от параметра отсортированный массив...

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.srand.php

Comment: 1. Не понятно, а вас авторизованные запросы? 2. Как вы их различаете (подключения)? Так же, хотелось бы, видеть ваши попытки, даже самые нелепые.

Comment: @КириллМалышев концовку первого абзаца вопроса прочитайте второй раз.

Comment: @teran, прочитал. И что? Если по строке домена получать число и устанавливать его как зерно, то перемешивание по одному и тому же алгоритму будет одинаковое для одинаковых доменов.

Comment: Сортируйте по значению хеша, который строится по сортируемому значению и по домену

Comment: @КириллМалышев мысль не понял сперва. плюсанул.

Answer (score 1):

По строке `$domain` получаем с помощью [циклического кода](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.crc32.php) целое число. Можно получать целое число как-то иначе. Главное, чтобы для одинаковых строк получались одинаковые числа. Далее, функцией [mt_srand](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mt-srand.php) устанавливаем это число как зерно генератора псевдослучайных чисел. Это гарантирует, что при одинаковых строках будут получаться одинаковые последовательности псевдослучайных чисел и массивы будут перемешаны одинаково. Здесь для перемешивания используется [алгоритм Фишера — Йетса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0).

```
function shuffleArray(&$array, $domain)
{
    $seed = crc32($domain);
    mt_srand($seed);
    for ($i = count($array) - 1; $i > 0; $i--)
    {
        $j = mt_rand(0, $i);
        $tmp = $array[$i];
        $array[$i] = $array[$j];
        $array[$j] = $tmp;
    }
}
```

[Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a8df953949520048d4f595612bda9ab20908015b):

```
$domain = "ya.ru";

$original = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
$shuffled = (array)$original;
shuffleArray($shuffled, $domain);
print_r($shuffled);

$shuffled = (array)$original;
shuffleArray($shuffled, $domain);
print_r($shuffled);
```

В обоих случаях вывод:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 7
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 9
    [3] => 8
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 3
    [7] => 1
    [8] => 5
    [9] => 2
)
```