# Есть ли способ генерации случайного массива используя ключ?

Tags: php, алгоритм, случайные-числа, генерация-случайных-данных

К примеру, вводим ключ "3572250778", получаем массив: {1 19 11 93 39 92 8 15 74 7}.
Вводим ключ "0817873553", получаем массив: {40 68 5 80 55 5 16 49 98 34}.
То есть при вводе конкретного ключа мы получаем конкретный случайный массив.
P.S Криптографическая безопасность значений не важна

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно использовать хеширование для ключа, чтобы получить целое число. Для этого подойдёт функция [crc32](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.crc32.php). Далее, этим числом задаём зерно генератора псевдослучайных чисел функцией [srand](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.srand.php) и генерируем массив.

```
$key = "3572250778";
$seed = crc32($key);
srand($seed);
$array = array();
foreach(range(0, 9) as $i) {
    $array[] = rand(0, 100);
}
var_dump($array);
```

Для одних и тех же ключей будут сгенерированы одни и те же целые числа. Для одних и тех же зёрен получатся одинаковые последовательности псевдослучайных чисел. Этим гарантируется, что для одинаковых ключей будут одинаковые массивы.

Comment: На похожий вопрос, кстати, уже отвечал. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1069114/235436

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!